# Sentinella Cannot be installed on ubuntu 14.10 above

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, dpkg, dependencies

From Ubuntu 14.10, Sentinella cannot be installed on Ubuntu, neither by software centre nor by terminal. The terminal ends with the error

```
appu@Ujjayini-Aspire-5738:~$ sudo apt-get install sentinella
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sentinella : Depends: libprocessui4a (>= 4:4.6.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And when I try to install libprocessui4a, It says:

```
appu@Ujjayini-Aspire-5738:~$ sudo apt-get install libprocessui4a
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libprocessui4a is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libprocessui4a' has no installation candidate
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Ubuntu 14.10, Cannonical has removed few KDE packages from the respositories. You can see that the dependency required for sentinella has been removed [from here](http://dreamhost.ubuntuupdates.org/package/kubuntu-ppa_backports/saucy/main/base/libprocessui4a). But yet there is hope while debian is here. There is a package to be downoaded before getting libprocessui4a. Here is a step by step how to.

1) go to 'https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libprocesscore4abi1'and scroll down to find the package which suits your computer architecture and then choose a mirror and download it.

2) Double-cick the package (libprocesscore4abi1_4.8.4-6_amd64.deb) and install it with software center

3) go to 'https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libs/libprocessui4a' and scroll down to find the package which suits your computer architecture and then choose a mirror and download it.

4)Double-click the package (libprocessui4a_4.8.4-6_amd64.deb) and install it with software centre

5)Now you can install Sentinella either from software centre or by typing`sudo apt-get install sentinella` in the terminal

Comment: I install it with yours instructions in UbuntuStudio 16.04 (64 bits) with sentinella package from https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/sentinella and ok, install, sentinella open but the network crash when try to use network, see terminal snapshot: http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1466857584.png